# NSString crashing program, how to fix?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have the following code:

.h

```
NSString *mainString;
```

.m

```
case 0: 
case 1:
case 2:
if ([typeTo textAlignment] == UITextAlignmentRight) {
     typeTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
     mainString = @"";
     [typeTo setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
     typeTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", typeTo.text, [sender tag]];
     mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]];
} else {
     typeTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", typeTo.text, [sender tag]];
     mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",mainString);
break;
```

Crashes on this line usually.

```
mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]];
```

Code works one then crashes.
both `typeTo.text` and `mainString` start as `@""`
And text alignment starts left.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the crash log message ?

Comment: can you share the full .h and .m file

Comment: You might want to test if `sender` really has tag property then: `if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(tag)] == YES)` Another important question, are you retaining `mainString` after using `stringWithFormat` ?

Comment: Try NSLogging mainString and [sender tag] individually and you should know which is the bug...

Comment: yes it does respond, the if statement returns YES

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", mainString);
NSLog(@"%d", [sender tag]);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9015/discussion-between-ravi-and-sirkaydian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using ARC, then you need to either retain the created string or create it with `alloc`. So either:

```
mainString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]] retain];
```

or better yet:

```
mainString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]];
```

This of course means you also need to `release` it before assigning a new value.

The reason for the crash is likely because you assign the autorelease instance to the pointer, then the object gets autoreleased but the pointer still points to that now-dead object.

Another way would be to use a property with `retain` or `copy` keyword. For strings, `copy` is usually the better solution because you could accidentally pass a `NSMutableString` and then later modify it.

**Edit** to answer comments:

In this case, to avoid a memory leak, the following should be done:

```
[mainString autorelease];
mainString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]];
```

The reason why this is necessary is because the `mainString` is used as an argument to create a new object, which is then in turn assigned to `mainString`. So before the `initWithFormat:` line, `mainString` pointed to a string object *A*. After that line, it now points to a new string object *B*. But you need to make sure to clean up *A*, which is why the autorelease is necessary. If you don't you'd have a memory leak and eventually your app will run out of memory.

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
NSString *tmp = mainString;
mainString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d", tmp, [sender tag]];
[tmp release];
```

The difference is that `autorelease` says: *I need this object for a short while, but some time after I leave this method it must be cleaned up if possible.* `release` says: *I don't need the object any more, please clean it up now if possible.*

Comment: Thanks it worked! It works without the release, do I have to release? Because I just want to keep adding to the string

Comment: Yes, you have to release otherwise you'd have a memory leak. However, in this case, you might want to use `autorelease` instead like this: `[mainString autorelease]; mainString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d", mainString, [sender tag]];`

Comment: hmm, don't quite understand, for it seems to work perfectly without that

Comment: Yes, it does work, but it leaks memory. This means that every time your method gets called, another string object gets "lost" (it still exists in memory, but you don't have any pointer to it any more and thus cannot clean it up). In other words, your app will use more and more memory until it crashes because there is no memory left.

Comment: oh okay, so before or after I call the "retain" do i call "autorelease"